# Sqlalchemy explicit locking of Postgresql table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, locking

I'm trying to explicitly lock a postgres table using this sqlalchemy command:

```
db.engine.execute('BEGIN; LOCK TABLE database_version IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;')
```

After this executes, if I go into the database client and run:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_locks;
```

There aren't any ACCESS EXCLUSIVE locks present.

If instead, I run the first command, but from inside the db client, it works as expected.

Is there a reason trying to get a table lock from sqlalchemy isn't working correctly?

Ideally, I want only one process to be able to query from and insert into the database_version table at a time.

Comment: When you say "after this executes", do you keep the connection open somehow? Does the script that executed that statement exit?

Comment: I put a time.sleep(20) in there after that line to give me time to switch over to the client and run the query.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out that I needed to start a nested transaction from the session object instead of trying to `BEGIN` one using straight SQL.

```
db.session.begin_nested()
db.session.execute('LOCK TABLE database_version IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;')
```

Then, i insert the new row:

```
new_version = DatabaseVersion(version=version + 1)
db.session.add(new_version)
db.session.commit()
```

and then finally commit again to close out the nested transaction:

```
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

with_lockmode("...") is now deprecated in sqlalchamy, see a reference here:
https://kite.com/python/docs/sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_lockmode

The solution now is to use:

```
session.query(database_version).with_for_update()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to lock the table.  I tested with the 2 simple, identical that do this on the same table and then sleep for 10 seconds.  They both were able to get the lock.  [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396201/2223706) OTOH does work (only 1 script gets the lock at the same time).

Comment: You need to actually execute the statement:
`session.execute(session.query(database_version).with_for_update())`